# Edit Adobe Illustrator PDF in web browser

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, itext

I am wondering if there is a way to edit pdf file (generated by Adobe Illustrator) in a web browser? They types of 'edit' that I'm after such as reposition element, changing color, changing text...etc and finally save the edited file.

iText seem like a good framework but not sure about it's capability.

Comment: iText is a server-side tool. It wasn't written to live in a web browser. You're asking people to recommend a tool or a library. That's not what StackOverflow is for.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically this is possible. But it would mean you would have to use a client-side PDF library capable of doing such edits. Such libraries are not common; in fact the only one I know of that could enable you to write something like this is created by PDFTron (https://www.pdftron.com).

(I know nothing more about that product; haven't used it or looked at it in detail)